# convert model class in dotnet core to json

Tags: .net, json, .net-core

I need to convert my entity framework entities for which I have created a model classes to json.
In other words i need to generate a json model from my entities. Is that possible please?
I have searched in internet, all I found is about serializing objects, but that does not serve my need, I don't to get the objects on json, I need the class it self to be converted to JSON.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg3sK.png)

Code:

```
class : 
    public class Course
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
```

What I need :

```
key : CourseID,
name : Course,
Properties:
{ 
CourseID: Int,
Title: String,
credits: Int
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work with simple properties like `strings` and `int`, direct reference types, arrays and generics. Although the generic will just be an object and not indicate whether it's a collection or something else.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ClassObject
{
    public class Course
    {
        public Collection<Enrollment> EnrollmentsGeneric { get; set; }
        public Enrollment[] EnrollmentsArray { get; set; }
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }
    }

    public class Enrollment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = GetProps(typeof(Course));
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict));
        }

        private static Dictionary<string, object> GetProps(Type type)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, object> {["name"] = type.Name};
            var props = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dict["properties"] = props;
            var p = type.GetProperties();

            foreach (var prop in p)
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                    props[prop.Name] = prop.PropertyType.ToString();
                else if (prop.PropertyType.IsArray)
                {
                    props[prop.Name] = new[]
                    {
                        GetProps(prop.PropertyType)
                    };
                }
                else if (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
                {
                    var itemType = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    props[prop.Name] = GetProps(itemType);
                }
                else
                {
                    props[prop.Name] = GetProps(prop.PropertyType);
                }
            }

            return dict;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
{
    "name": "Course",
    "properties": {
        "EnrollmentsGeneric": {
            "name": "Enrollment",
            "properties": {
                "Id": "System.Int32"
            }
        },
        "EnrollmentsArray": [
            {
                "name": "Enrollment[]",
                "properties": {
                    "Length": "System.Int32",
                    "LongLength": "System.Int64",
                    "Rank": "System.Int32",
                    "SyncRoot": {
                        "name": "Object",
                        "properties": {}
                    },
                    "IsReadOnly": "System.Boolean",
                    "IsFixedSize": "System.Boolean",
                    "IsSyn\r\nchronized": "System.Boolean"
                }
            }
        ],
        "CourseID": "System.Int32",
        "Title": "System.String",
        "Credits": "System.Int32"
    }
}
```